# SQL Key Column doesn't exist when ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE book
ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
REFERENCES category (category_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Whenever I run this ALTER TABLE statement, it keeps coming back with, "Error Code: 1072. Key column 'category_id' does not exist."

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I'm having problems adding a foreign key to one of my tables. I just started learning SQL last week so any help would be appreciated!

My CREATE TABLE statements are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book
(book_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(100) not null,
description TEXT not null,
price DEC(18,2) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category
(category_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
code1 VARCHAR(20) not null,
name1 VARCHAR(100) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You need to add category_id column in table book before referencing it as FK with table category.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category
(category_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
code1 VARCHAR(20) not null,
name1 VARCHAR(100) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This Table has the Primay Key category_id but below table has no Column 
as "category_id"  which is being referenced in the Alter Command.Add
Column "category_id in below table and then execute Alter command.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book
(book_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(100) not null,
description TEXT not null,
price DEC(18,2) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete script then

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book
(book_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(100) not null,
description TEXT not null,
price DEC(18,2) not null,
category_id INT not null 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category
(category_id INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
code1 VARCHAR(20) not null,
name1 VARCHAR(100) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE book
ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
REFERENCES category (category_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```